# c# md5 and php md5 not mach

Tags: c#, php, md5

I am trying to use c# md5 and php md5 to calculate the same result but they give different results. The c# code must be the same as the php code.

```
public string ToMD5(string orderId, string statusCode, string secretKey)
{
   string key = orderId + "+" + statusCode;
   key = Base64Encode(key);
   MD5 m = System.Security.Cryptography.MD5.Create();
   byte[] h = m.ComputeHash(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(key + secretKey));
   string r = "";

   foreach (byte b in h)
   {
       r += b.ToString("X2");
   }

   return r;
}
```

And here is the php code:

```
$key = $orderid."+".$status;
$prec = base64_encode($key);
$prec = $prec.$SecretKey;
$prec = md5($prec);
echo $prec;
```

> c#  returns  : CEC71705E5A25CCD21609B72053539FC
>
> php returns  : f1542715b25b302553119fda1e8567bb

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Are you 100% sure all the values are **exactly** the same? Have you gone through the code line-by-line, as it is running, to make sure of it? You will get a different hash if but a single bit is different.

Comment: Please edit – or delete – this question as its currently extremely low value. It seems clear that `Encoding.Default.GetBytes(key + secretKey)` and `$prec.$SecretKey` aren't the same sequence of bytes but it's not clear why that's useful to anyone.

Comment: @KennyEvitt  that two codes gives same result we tested . did you test it ?

Comment: @safa If the two sets of code give the same result then there's no point in keeping this question. This question is only useful *if* the two sets of code do *not* produce the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These 2 lines produce the same MD5 hash value:

```
  echo md5("12345+200OKSecret");
```

and

```
new List<byte>(MD5.Create().ComputeHash(Encoding.Default.GetBytes("12345+200OKSecret"))).ForEach(x => Console.Write("{0:X2}",x));
```

Results:

```
8df9a16122b34e41d49ad11d9f1e0c73
```

and

```
8DF9A16122B34E41D49AD11D9F1E0C73
```

Check the values of the strings you are hashing - they must be different.